# Where is the Windows Workflow Xaml Vocabulary Specification?

Tags: xaml, workflow

I've been able to find *Xaml Object Mapping Specification*, *WPF Xaml Vocabulary Specification*, and *Silverlight Xaml Vocabulary Specification* documents online but no *WF Xaml Vocabulary Specification* document for Windows Workflows.  I want to be able to specify workflows without using a Visual Studio IDE.

Does anybody know if this specification exists and if so, where to find it?

Comment: Could you add some links to these documents you did find? I would like to have a look at those.

Answer (score 3):

WF vocabulary specification is not yet published.

All other Xaml-related specifications can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19600

Answer (score 0):

[xps spec](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/xps/xpsspec.mspx)

may or may not be up to date with the ecma work

[XAML object spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/6/0A6F7755-9AF5-448B-907D-13985ACCF53E/[MS-XAML].pdf)

[WPF XAML spec 2006](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/6/0A6F7755-9AF5-448B-907D-13985ACCF53E/[MS-WPFXV].pdf)

[Silverlight xaml spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/6/0A6F7755-9AF5-448B-907D-13985ACCF53E/[MS-SLXV].pdf)

So far there is no WF spec.

Douglas